# How to retrieve featured images from custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, wordpress

I have created Custom slideshow post type.Images set as featured images for each new slide post. I want to retrieve these image in slideshow template.

HTML markup for this slide template is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="my-slider" class="my-slider">

<li>
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/photo/123456" target="_blank"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image1"/></a>
<div class="my-description">
<h3>Image one</h3>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/photo/1234565" target="_blank"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image2"/></a>
<div class="my-description">
<h3>Image two</h3>
</div>
</li>


<li>
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/photo/12345655" target="_blank"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image3"/></a>
<div class="my-description">
<h3>Image three</h3>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/photo/12345666" target="_blank"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image4"/></a>
<div class="my-description">
<h3>Image four oner</h3>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This HTML gives four slide images as I hard-coded it.How to retrieve attached image dynamically from wordpress custom post type to get the same result?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by **How to retrieve attached image dynamically from wordpress custom post type**?

Comment: I mean I want to get my featured images from custom post type.Once I have my template I dont want to add each image in template as shown above. I want to get any number of images by simply creating new slide post with featured image.

Comment: How you intend to "post" data for those images? Database driven (3 columns) or written in a file as a string for ie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this by getting array of all images from custom post type and storing it in variable $myimage. 
$myimage[0] is the src for img tag which need to catch in loop to get all images

```
global $post;
$args = array(
'post_type' =>'slideshow',
'numberposts' => -1,
'orderby' => 'menu_order' );

$slider_posts = get_posts($args); ?>
<?php if($slider_posts) { ?>
<?php // start the loop
foreach($slider_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
$myimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply query for your custom post type? An example:

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type');
query_posts( $args );

// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  //Do your stuff  

  //You can access your feature image like this:
  the_post_thumbnail();
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Below is the example to retrive feature image. 

$args = array('post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type');
query_posts( $args );

// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

//Image size small,large or medium
  the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail',imagesize);?>


}
?>
endwhile;
```